# wordpress plugin gogole maps issue with error: ApiNotActivatedMapError

Tags: wordpress, api, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

relatively new to word press.

I recently bought a theme with a tevolution plugin that encompassed a map setting that displays the google map on the website. I was prompted to add an API key to follow the steps, which I did and add it. It was working ad stopped and could never seem to fix the issue.

I regenerated a key and still, the same issue has persisted. In my console, I get the error: ApiNotActivatedMapError which they advise for me to enable the Java script which I can see enabled.

Please can you guys advise another solution for this issue? the google maps version I have is "3.40.3"

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the relevant API in the GCP (Google Cloud Platform) console? Apart from creating and adding API keys, you also need to enable the API in question for your GCP project. From top left menu: Go to API & Services --> Library and Enable relevant API for your project.